# Example of linear transformation and basis with different dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find an example of a linear transformation:

$T : \mathcal{P}_2 \longrightarrow V = \left\{ \left[ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{matrix} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^4\space | \space x +y = z+w \right\}$

And respective basis of $\mathcal{P}_2$ and $V$ so $[T]_{\mathcal{C},\mathcal{B}} = I_3$

I fail to see how this question can be solved the domain has dimension 3 and codomain dimension 4 (the image has dimension 3 so T is not surjective)

Comment: Note that $V$ is not all of $\Bbb R^4$, but rather only the hyperplane determined by your condition $x+y=z+w$. Note that $x+y=z+w$ is equivalent to $x+y-z-w=0$, and that this `is' the dot product:
$$(x,y,z,w)\cdot (1,1,-1,-1)=0,$$
so you are taking the hyperplane orthogonal to $(1,1,-1,-1)$. Hopefully that's of some pedagogical value (for example, might give you one way of seeing how the answerer picked a basis).

Answer (score 0):

The codomain has dimension 3 (and not 4) if you observe carefully. The rough idea is that an element of $V$ is fully determined by giving arbitrary values to $x$, $y$ and $z$ (so that $w$ is uniquely determined by the relation $x+y = z+w$.

Now, consider a basis for $V$, say
$\{(1,0,1,0), (0,0,1,-1), (0,1,1,0)\}$.

Take the usual basis of $\mathcal{P}_2$, that is, $\{1,x,x^2\}$.

Take the map at the level of bases sending $1 \mapsto (1,0,1,0)$, $x \mapsto (0,0,1,-1)$ and $x^2 \mapsto (0,1,1,0)$.

Extend this linearly to a map from $\mathcal{P}_2$ onto $V$. This will be an isomorphism since it maps a basis onto a basis.